# Selecting session variable with an IF statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code to send variables to a datagrid on another page

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int agent = int.Parse(txtAgencyCode.Text);
        Session["para1"] = agent;
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('http://localhost:50771/WebSite4/Datagrid.aspx'); return false;");

    }

    protected void btnTitleSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["para2"] = txtTitleSearch.Text;
        btnTitleSearch.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('http://localhost:50771/WebSite4/Datagrid.aspx'); return false;");
    }
```

and this code on the other page that uses the session variable from button one

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int field1 = (int)(Session["para"]);
        localhost.Service ws = new localhost.Service();
        GridView1.DataSource = ws.GetJobsByAgencyID(field1);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

What i cannot figure out is how to make an if statement (or even if it will be an if statement that is used) to decide which parameter is passed to my datagrid.

For info there will be another 3- 4 controlos on the default page (Only one of which will be activated) and the parameters will take diffeent types.

**EDIT**
So sorry you all found my question hard to understand, im not by any means a profesional or even what yuo may call a competent. 
James Hill and Ravi gave me pretty much what I was after (need to test but looks like it). Thanks all for trying :D

Comment: what would be your condition?

Comment: @jadarnel27 you made me laugh hard!

Comment: ...and why convert `txtAgencyCode.Text` to an `int` before storing it in `Session["para1"]`? Would it not be easier to simply store the text value, then convert the Session value when it is needed?

Comment: @jp2code i don't know if the session-variables-values are stored by cast to an object ... so if he parses it once and then stores is as object, he can easily cast it back to int and not doing a conversion every time accessing the session-variable!

Comment: @Dylan it's not a bad question per se (it's nicely formatted). You just didn't make yourself clear. You should always be very obvious about what your *actual question* is (more or less "How can I check if a particular Session variable exists?").  Anyways, sorry if we were a little harsh =)  Good luck!

Comment: @jadarnel27 maybe if id said something like "I want to bind the data table to a certain datasource with variable typed parameters depending on what button is pressed in the original page"? Would that have helped?

Comment: And I've had it a lot tougher on here believe me...:D

Comment: @DylanJackson Yes, that is a bit more clear!  Good stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood correctly, you need branching based on value stored in your session,

you can try like this

```
  if (Session["para1"] != null) 
    {
      int AgentCode = Convert.ToInt32(Session["para1"].ToString());

      //Search by AgentCode 
           GridView1.DataSource = ws.GetJobsByAgencyID(AgentCode );
            GridView1.DataBind();

    }

   else if (Session["para2"] != null)
    {
      string title = Session["para1"].ToString();

       //Search by title
       GridView1.DataSource = ws.GetJobsByAgencyID(title );
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
   else
   {
      // your default parameters
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're question is a bit difficult to understand. I think what you're asking is how to determine if a session variable exists. For that, simply use:

```
if (Session["para"] != null) {
    //para exists
}
else if (Session["para2"] != null) {
    //para2 exists
}
...
```

Comment: this won't compile - an extra parenthesis :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, :). Fixed. What would I do without my IDE?

Answer (score 0):

If the data isn't sensitive, rather than setting a session variable, I recommend using the querystring in your windowopen and passing the param that way.

```
 Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('http://localhost:50771/WebSite4/Datagrid.aspx?dataPassed=1'); return false;");
```

In the code behind of the grid, do a case statement:

```
int data= (int)(Request.Querystring["dataPassed"]);
switch(data)
{  case 1:
       dosomething();
       break;
   case 2:
       dosomethingelse();
       break
   default:
      throw;
      break:
}
```

Comment: ... and why? what benifit would this solution have over the ops actual implementation?!

Comment: No server resources are used in querystrings. Also, querystring is stateless and you gain portability as you could move this functionality to client side if necessary, which would allow for changes with no recompile. Use session variables if you plan to reuse the value. If not, client side methods are preferred.

Comment: wow ... you did not get the question ... it doesn't really matter if the op is using client- or server-side to store some values ... somewhere the op has to do an if-statement, that won't change. so which legitimation does your answer have?

Comment: If I didn't get it, apparently I'm not the only one. See the comments and vote of the question. On SO, we need to give what we feel is the best answer, if that means changing implementation to help the OP to achieve best practices, so be it.

Comment: the main problem isn't your suggestion to use queryString over session - the main problem is, that this little change won't change/improve anything in the ops requirement (except not involving server-side that much). the inital question was quite clear, when it comes to the word "condition" - your answer did not contain any answer for a condition in any way! it's like you ask "how can i open an umbrella?" and you answer "take the blue one" ... got it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you have another session variable called context?

```
string context = Session["context"];

switch(context)
{
case "titlesearch":
//do the things 
break;

}
```

syntax is not checked, only the idea.